# How to SUM a case statement containing a nested select statement?

Tags: sql-server, case, subquery

This is my initial query:

```
select 
CASE WHEN a.TO_WG_ID is null 
and a.CREATED_DATE_TIME = 
(select min(b.created_date_time) from ymtn.message b 
where b.thread_id = a.thread_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS "Created"
from ymtn.MESSAGE a 
left join YMTN.WORKGROUP b
ON a.FROM_WG_ID=b.WORKGROUP_ID
where b.WORKGROUP_ID='1STOP_PROCESS'
```

It gives me one column with a bunch of 1' and 0's. All I want out is the sum..just a number e.g. 1691. If I put a SUM in front of the case statement I get this error:
**Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.** So how do I do this? I have made it work with this query:

```
select count(CREATED_DATE_TIME) as 'Created'
from ymtn.MESSAGE a
LEFT JOIN YMTN.WORKGROUP b
ON a.FROM_WG_ID=b.WORKGROUP_ID
where CREATED_DATE_TIME=(SELECT MIN(b.CREATED_DATE_TIME) FROM YMTN.MESSAGE b WHERE
 b.THREAD_ID = a.THREAD_ID)
and a.TO_WG_ID is null
and b.WORKGROUP_ID='1STOP_PROCESS'
```

However I want it to work in the case statement and not have to move the nested select down to the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw the whole thing into a subquery and sum that?

```
select sum(Created)
from (
    select 
    CASE WHEN a.TO_WG_ID is null 
    and a.CREATED_DATE_TIME = 
    (select min(b.created_date_time) from ymtn.message b 
    where b.thread_id = a.thread_id) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END AS "Created"
    from ymtn.MESSAGE a 
    left join YMTN.WORKGROUP b
    ON a.FROM_WG_ID=b.WORKGROUP_ID
    where b.WORKGROUP_ID='1STOP_PROCESS'
) a
```